# How to edit the inline-style of a re-frame component to add a scroll to an overflow-x property?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, clojurescript, re-frame

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project executing the command `cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, then I choose `shadow-cljs`, also `shadow` for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the build option. I can watch changes on the UI on `localhost:3005`.

Using Brave browser and the Dev Tools, I managed to do the following addition:

[image]

As you see, it is a scroll (in blue), added via element style tweak (in red), affecting the selected div (in green).

Ok. Now, I want to make this change perpetual. I found the re-frame component on the source code:

```clj
[:div.card-body.text-left.shadow.p-3.mb-5.bg-white.rounded
           
    [rc/v-box
            :gap       "10px"
            :children
    
      (omitted...)

 
                        :children [[delete-je-button-rc the-entry]]]]]]
```

I decided to do the following addition:

```clj
          [:div.card-body.text-left.shadow.p-3.mb-5.bg-white.rounded

           :style {:overflow-x  "scroll"}

           [rc/v-box
            :gap       "10px"
            :children

             (omitted...)
 
                        :children [[delete-je-button-rc the-entry]]]]]]
```

That did not workout.

Following @ThomasHeller's suggestion, I also tried:

```clj
[:div.card-body.text-left.shadow.p-3.mb-5.bg-white.rounded
          ;[smart-je-header (:name the-entry) (:id the-entry)] ;deprecated for inline-editor-je-name
           {:style {:overflow-x  "scroll"}}
```

Also:

```clj
[:div.card-body.text-left.shadow.p-3.mb-5.bg-white.rounded.overflow-x-scroll
          ;[smart-je-header (:name the-entry) (:id the-entry)] ;deprecated for inline-editor-je-name
```

And even both of them:

```clj
          [:div.card-body.text-left.shadow.p-3.mb-5.bg-white.rounded.overflow-x-scroll
          ;[smart-je-header (:name the-entry) (:id the-entry)] ;deprecated for inline-editor-je-name
           {:style {:overflow-x  "scroll"}}
```

Unfortunately, nothing worked out.

There is something in the source code causing an overwrite, see the pic above:

[image]

I am clueless about how to debug this and find the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular `:div` element only supports the usual attribute map, so you set it via:

```
[:div.card-body.text-left.shadow.p-3.mb-5.bg-white.rounded
 {:style {:overflow-x  "scroll"}} ...]
```

This appears to be using [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/), so you can also set this via its [overflow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow) classes instead and drop the `:style` map completely.

```
[:div.card-body.text-left.shadow.p-3.mb-5.bg-white.rounded.overflow-x-scroll
 ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again @ThomasHeller. I have been learning a lot with you.
Unfortunately, none of them worked out. I have just updated my question. Also, I do not believe the project uses Tailwind. I am not 100% sure, though. I have even made a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651431/how-to-know-if-a-project-uses-tailwind-css

Comment: Your second screenshot unfortunately is too cropped and does not show necessary info. What is the selected DOM element? It either appears that you have the `body` element selected? Or none of the CSS classes actually exist? From the naming of the classes I assumed it is tailwind but it doesn't need to be. The first one showed the expected CSS for tailwind although with an unexpected `!important`?